# Revolution of a solid - mandatory disk method

Tags: calculus

I know I am doing something wrong. Anyways

$x = 2$

$x = 3$

$y = 16 - x^4$

$y = 0$

about the y axis

So about the y axis means I need everything in terms of y. Easy enough, that is just one term.

$$y = 16 - x^4$$

$$x = (y - 16)^\frac{1}{4}$$

Then I intgrate with respect to y.

$$\pi \int_2^3 (y - 16)^\frac{1}{4} dy$$

$$\pi * \frac{4}{5}(y-16)^\frac{5}{4}$$

I know that is correct but I can't calculate that without imaginary numbers. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: My picture is fine now but I don't  understand how to apply this method to a triple or quad bound revolution

Comment: Is this a trick question? 16-x^2 never crosses x= 2 and x =3.

Comment: You can decide later whether it is a trick question. The curve looks somewhat like a downward facing parabola, sort of. The region we are rotating is **below** the $x$-axis, to the **right** of the curve, and to the **left** of $x=3$. (It could be interpreted differently, perhaps the wording of the real problem was more precise.)

Comment: Yes. I take it you have drawn the picture, I gave a verbal description of the region a few comments ago. Look at it and the picture. The system objects to long strings of comments, so soon I will remove most of mine, suggest you do the same.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I couldn't see it without your description but I get the region now.

Comment: Good! It was in an "unusual" position, at least compared to other volume problems you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid your answer is not correct.

You have a sign error at the start: $y=16-x^4$ becomes $x=(16-y)^{1/4}$, not $x=(y-16)^{1/4}$. That explains why you came up against having to take roots of negative numbers.

Also, in your integral, $y$ needs to go from $16-3^4=-65$ to $0$, not from $1$ to $2$. Think about it backwards: you need to integrate over the region where $x=(16-y)^{1/4}$ goes from $2$ to $3$. If you integrate over $2\leq y\leq 3$, then what you are really doing is integrating over the region where $x$ goes from $(14)^{1/4}$ to $(13)^{1/4}$.

Comment: It is 2 to 3 because those are the y values and  I have pi/

Comment: @Paul: Sorry, I misread about the $\pi$. But I think my other points are correct.

Comment: I don't follow. If I am integrating with respect to y then arent my y values bounded from y = 2 and y = 3 as defined by the problem?

Comment: I have a good picture I just don't understand how to triple bound an object being revolved, it isn't in the book at all.